# How do I auto-enable GitHub dependabot alerts? API?

Tags: github, dependabot

How do I auto-enable GitHub dependabot alerts? Can it be enabled via API?

Comment: For security updates, or version updates?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Just dependabot alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For repositories of a user: alerts and security updates can be enabled for all repositories at https://github.com/settings/security_analysis
- For repositories in an organization: the settings live at [https://github.com/organizations/{org}/settings/security_analysis](https://github.com/organizations/%7Borg%7D/settings/security_analysis), where `{org}` is a placeholder for the organization

There is a [REST API for dependabot alerts](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/dependabot/alerts?apiVersion=2022-11-28), but it doesn't let you manage if alerts or updates are enabled.